# Attempt to mutate immutable object with replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string

Keep getting this crash error and banging my head against the wall trying to get this code to work. The string is set to a `NSMutableString`. Any suggestions on what needs to be corrected?

```
@implementation JSONLoaderIngreds

- (NSArray *)ingredientsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response  error:nil];

    // NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSMutableString *removewords in [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"ingredients"]){
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"tablespoons " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cups " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cup " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        //[removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" Cup " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];

         [locations addObjectsFromArray:[removewords componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];

        NSLog(@"%@", locations);
    }

    // Return the array of Location objects
    return locations;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableString *removewords in [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"ingredients"]` just casts strings from jsonDictionary to NSMutableString, this can't make any string mutable.

Replace it to `NSString *removewords in [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"ingredients"]` and use `NSMutableString * mutableRemovewords = [removewords mutableCopy]`.

Comment: Awesome!  That worked.  I knew it was something simple, but I couldn't figure it out....still learning.  Thanks!